# Restrict users from a GET request to access admin and _id details

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, server-side, get-request

I am configuring the server-side and I am trying to restrict users to access their _id and admin field set to false by default by a GET request. The reason is the I want to avoid users with a PUT request to change their admin role to TRUE and then gain admin abilities. GET request is for the purpose of showing their details on the front-end. The database i am using is MongoDB. This is what my code looks like:

**Route.js**

```
router.route('/my-profile')
.get(authenticate.verifyUser, (req,res,next) => {
    User.findOne({ _id: req.user._id })
    .populate('properties')
    .then((user) => {
        res.statusCode = 200
        res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json')
        res.json(user)
    }, (err) => next(err))
    .catch((err) => next(err))
})
.post(authenticate.verifyUser, (req,res,next) => {
    res.statusCode = 403
    res.end('POST operation not supported on /my-profile')
}) 
.put(authenticate.verifyUser, (req,res,next) => {
    User.findByIdAndUpdate(req.user._id, {
        $set: req.body
    }, { new: true })// the new will return the updated in the reply
    .then((user) => {
        res.statusCode = 200
        res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json')
        res.json(user)
    }, (err) => next(err))
    .catch((err) => next(err))
}) 
.delete(authenticate.verifyUser, (req,res,next) => {
    User.findByIdAndRemove(req.user._id)
    .then((resp) => {
        res.statusCode = 200
        res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json')
        res.json(resp) // send response back to the client
    }, (err) => next(err))
    .catch((err) => next(err))
})
```

and this is what it shows up until now in Postman:

```
{
    "admin": false,
    "_id": "5f9ee6c33beb0101e858af32",
    "username": "paul",
    "title": "mr",
    "email": "arko@gmail.com",
    "firstName": "Mauri",
    "lastName": "Polin",
    "address": "23 rorer",
    "postcode": "se2 ofe",
    "country": "United Kingdom",
    "phoneNumber": "2",
    "gender": "male",
    "lookingFor": "rent",
    "joinDate": "2020-10-30T00:00:00.000Z",
    "createdAt": "2020-11-01T16:48:03.910Z",
    "updatedAt": "2020-11-01T17:38:52.736Z",
    "__v": 0
}
```

Does anyone can be of any help? Thank you!

Comment: have you tested if a user can change that? Also, I bet admin only means if they have been registered under admin database or not. Which won't change much for them.

Comment: yes I did, it does change it. admin is something that should only be changed to true from the database or shell, but no user should be able to access that and then being able to see an admin dashboard or some other potential things such edit or delete. The user schema present the admin field set to false as default. Do you think i should remove the admin field and abilitate the admin in another way?

Comment: Maybe, but wait for more people to help